# Problems with whitespaces on Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script to remove items on a folder:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\FUNDACIÓN CB\Pedro Corchero Murga\Info de vídeos\Proyectos\* | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

The problem is that I'm having issues with the path because it have whitespaces and gives me this error:

```
Get-ChildItem : No se encuentra ningún parámetro de posición que acepte el argumento 'Corchero'.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Get-ChildItem D:\FUNDACIÓN CB\Pedro Corchero Murga\Info de vídeos\Pro ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add quotes `" "` to the path:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\FUNDACION CB\........"
```